# Delete "work or school" account from a Microsoft account?

Tags: microsoft-account

I want to delete the "work or school" account from my Microsoft Account. In the end my private account should remain with all its connected services as-is, but the work or school account with its connected services should be deleted.

How to do that?

I tried contacting Microsoft, but their customer support says that I have to contact business support for "work or school"-account related questions, and I can't contact business support because I'm not a business...

Please, somebody out there, help me.

In addition, I'm really scared of performing any action. It would be really bad if I lose access to my private account's servies and as far as I've read if you delete your private account you cannot recreate an account with this e-mail address ever again which would be an epic problem.

Comment: In Start, Settings, Accounts, if you are in control on the Account, you can click on it and select "Remove"  . Are you in control of your accounts or did someone else set up the accounts.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  A normal Microsoft Account cannot actually be a "work or school" account. Are you simply attempting to disassociate your "school or work" email from your local profile?

Comment: I'm not talking of a Windows machine. I'm talking about the online account. When I login at https://account.microsoft.com I am asked whether I want to login with my "work or school" account or my "personal" account.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm locally logged in with a local user account, not a Microsoft Account. I'm not talking about a Windows machine.

Comment: Same question as I had of your machine:  Are you in control of your online accounts? or did someone else set up the other account?  Did you set up two accounts?

Comment: @John: Yes. I set up my personal account, and by accident (by setting up a Microsoft Partner account) also the work or school accountl.

Comment: Try again with Microsoft Support with your explanation and as if they will delete it.

Comment: @D.R.- If this question is about an online account then it is out of scope here at Super User.  At the end of the day you Microsoft needs to help you with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whoever stumbles on this page: I've managed to delete it and summarized it in a blog post: https://www.rauch.io/2020/06/01/how-to-delete-your-microsoft-work-or-school-account/